# How to group columns for a Reporting Services Matrix?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, matrix

I want to display data in a reporting services matrix. It is an access peak matrix, in a way that days are rows, and hours are columns. My procedure returns data like this:

```
Day / Hour / Peak
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 00:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 01:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 02:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 03:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 04:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 05:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 06:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 07:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 08:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 09:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 10:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 11:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 12:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 13:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 14:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 15:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 16:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 17:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 18:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 19:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 20:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 21:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 22:00:00 0
2010-05-01 00:00:00.000 2010-05-01 23:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 00:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 01:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 02:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 03:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 04:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 05:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 06:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 07:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 08:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 09:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 10:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 11:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 12:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 13:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 14:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 15:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 16:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 17:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 18:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 19:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 20:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 21:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 22:00:00 0
2010-05-02 00:00:00.000 2010-05-02 23:00:00 0
...
```

My row field in reporting services is the day, column is hour, detail is peak. But when I render the result, it repeats the hour columns for each row.

How to group all 1AM, all 2AM, and so on, given this dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the procedure result was that time was 1AM, 2AM, etc, but the date part is different for each date.

I just ignored the date part and everything is fine and grouped together.